# Is a CNAME required if domain registrar and hosting company are the same?

Tags: dns, cname

I had a domain through web.com as well as hosting with them.  I tried a new company, zenfolio, and after the year was up I decided to stop using them.  The issue is now the site keeps pointing to an empty zenfolio page.  I removed the CNAME record directing to zenfolio, waited a while and nothing seemed to happen.  So I Added a new cname - "WWW" and "domain name" but nothing is occurring with that adjustment either.  Should I simply remove the CNAME as I am using the original hosting site again?

Comment: Give the true name involved if you want to have some help.

Answer (score 1):

A CNAME is just an alias that resolves to an address. You don’t have to have them at all, but it’s a common convention. Ultimately your CNAME must resolve to an A record with the address of your site.

You need to first find out how your domain name is being resolved and by who (old provider or new?) and then add the right entries (A or CNAME as appropriate). A good resource for these occasions is http://dns.squish.net - put in your site name and it will show you how it resolves.